# Java method naming conventions

Tags: java, naming-conventions, javabeans

I have a boolean field called `showLabels` in a Bean class, and I want to provide getter and setter methods for it. The setter will be `setShowLabels`, but should the getter be `isShowingLabels`, `isShowLabels` (that's really weird sounding), or `setShowLabels`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be `isShowLabels` weird as that may sound, [that's the convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBean). You could always rename the boolean to `showingLabels`.

Comment: +1, and more importantly than that it's convention, it's also *required* if you want to use classes like `Introspector`.

Comment: additionally, if using Eclipse, it can generate it for you.

Comment: Thank you. I will probably rename the field to showingLabels, and have `setShowingLabels` and `isShowingLabels`.

Comment: @alpha123 - Glad to help! If you like the answer click the checkmark to mark it as correct.

Comment: Follow the convention, when when it sucks :-) Will save time and pain later.

Comment: @adam it said I had to wait 5 minutes. I waited, and now have.